# If p is prime, how to check whether ap + b is prime or not using a fast algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, primes, number-theory

We have three numbers **a**, **b**, and **p**. **p** is a big prime number but **a** and **b** are much smaller that **p**.

How to find out whether **ap + b** is prime or not using a fast algorithm?

We don't want to use BigInteger classes and something like that.

Note that we can know some other things about **p**. For example **p % m** can be calculated easily if **m** be small.

Comment: if you can check p for primeness, why cant you calculate ap+b and check it for primeness, given a and b are small? can you show us your algo?

Comment: "big" is vague. How big?

Comment: @NormanM We only know p is prime.

Comment: @JohnColeman It cannot fit into a 64-bit integer.

Comment: is it big enough to store in [`__int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html)? If it's bigger then use an arbitrary precision type

Comment: In a world with RSA keys in the hundreds and even thousands of bits, an inability to store something in a 64-bit word is no great reason to not run Miller-Rabin on it. Just use a big integer library.

Comment: BTW Latex syntax doesn't work on SO.

Comment: You should probably ask this on Math Overflow instead.

Comment: I don't know of any fast algorithm for primes with this structure. I'm reminded of Pocklington's Theorem, but this does not quite fit. This is more math than programming, so you might be able to get a better answer on [math](https://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Chloe: are **a** and **b** primes as well?

Comment: @CodeHunter No. But if there will be an algorithm in that case is very good.

Comment: I don't think that knowing the primality of p helps you at all knowing about that of ap+b. For instance, primality of p doesn't tell you the primality of p+2 (except that twin primes are more dense).

Comment: @CodeHunter: if a, b are odd, ap+b is even !

Comment: @JamesKPolk and John-coleman Thanks!

Comment: @YvesDaoust: No. consider `p` = 2, `a` = 3 and `b` = 5. `ap+b` = 11 which is prime and not even! Note that `a` and `b` are odd.

Comment: @CodeHunter: ha - ha. (Note that the OP specified a, b much smaller than p.)

Comment: Knowing that p is prime doesn't really help you at all.  Might as well run Miller-Rabin

Comment: @YvesDaoust We can know some other things about p. For example p%m can be calculated easily if m be small.

Comment: @Chloe: what use is this if there is no relation between the primalities of p and q = ap+b ? p and q are two independent numbers.

Comment: All numbers larger than `p` can be written as `ap+b` for some `a`, `b`. Thus without any additional assumptions, you can't really hope for anything which is much faster than a primality test for the resulting number (Though as @JoopEggen showed in their excellent answer some assumptions on `a` and `b` trivially rule out the result being prime)

Comment: Also -- do you really want a *fast* algorithm, or is the goal to find an algorithm which can be done on numbers whose size is not much larger than `p` (e.g. `p` can fit in 64 bits but `ap+b` can't -- what can you do while staying within 64 bits)?

Comment: @JohnColeman `p` cannot be stores in any integer structure in programming languages. For example has at most `10^6` digits.

Answer (score 3):

This question fits more the math partner forum.

If `gcd(a, b) != 1` then it is not a prime.

If `(a + b) % 2 != 1` then it is not a prime.

Looking at `3.7 + 4` not being prime leads to yet another rule.

So do some math, i.e.

```
(a % b) * (p % b)
```

must be prime, though `p % b` is out-of-the-question.

Comment: What do you mean by "p % b is out-of-the-question."? Sorry! My English is not quite good.

Comment: Please look at the problem statement again. I have added some more details.

Comment: Just wanted to say: `p % b` is not doable, as p is very large. But you are saying `p % m` _can_ be easily calculated somehow. However a mathemetical forum can be more interesting.

Comment: No. You're wrong. In `p % b` only p is big and `b` is small. So `p % b` can be calculated easily in `O(number of digits of p) = O(logn)`. Assume `p` is stored as a string of characters. So by an iteration over digits of `p`, `p % b` can be computed.

Comment: Thanks for the O, and there are many heuristics for these kind of modulo problems. If % 13, keep the number in base 13, and check only the least significant digit O(1).

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption** : You are allowed to use BigInteger class.

You can convert the form `ap+b` into BigInteger and check for primality. Below is the code to do so in java. Since `a` and `b` are not very large as per OP and are  `int`, they can be stored in int. Since `p` is very large, we will store it in BigInteger class

Hope this helps:

```
    String p = "2432902008176640029";   
    int a = 30, b = 101;     
    BigInteger f = new BigInteger(p);
    BigInteger f1 = f.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(a));
    BigInteger f2 = f1.add(BigInteger.valueOf(b));
    System.out.println(f2.isProbablePrime(1));
```

`f2.isProbablePrime(1)` checks if the number formed by `ap+b` is a prime or not with certainty of `1`.

This technique used in BigInteger class for checking prime is actually [Miller - Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) primality test implemented in an efficient way.